# Authentication component for ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I would like to have a universal component that gets called every time I navigate to routes. The main purpose of this component is authentication. To better illustrate what I need I have this example if vue.js:

```
const routes = [
    { path: '/', component: Login, meta: { auth: false } },
    { path: '/dashboard', component: Dashboard, meta: { auth: true } },
];

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if( to.meta.auth ) {
       // run auth, then next();
    } else {
       next();
    }
})
```

I can I achieve smth like this in ReactJs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the documentation of `react-router` (assuming you are going to use this router library) there is an example of how to implement authenticated routes: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow

Using your example you could implement it like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

import Login from './Login';
import Dashboard from './Dashboard';

const routes = [
  { path: '/', component: (props) => <Login {...props} />, meta: { auth: false } },
  { path: '/dashboard', component: (props) => <Dashboard {...props} />, meta: { auth: true } },
];

export default class MyRouter extends Component {

  isLoggedin() {
    // run auth check that will return true/false 
    return true;
  }

  render() {
    // if loggedin => render component, if not => redirect to the login page
    const PrivateRoute = ({ component: RouteComponent, ...rest }) => (
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={props => (
        this.isLoggedin() ? (
          <RouteComponent {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />
        )
      )}
      />
    );

    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          {routes.map((route, index) => (
            route.meta.auth ?
              <PrivateRoute key={index} path={route.path} exact component={route.component} />
            :
              <Route key={index} path={route.path} exact component={route.component} />
          ))}
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

Inside the PrivateRoute we will check the auth status with `this.isLoggedIn()` and based on the returned boolean, the component or a Redirect (to the login page for example) is rendered.

Comment: Can I make an ajax call to define if its true or false?

Comment: Sure, inside `isLoggedin()` you can return a fetch Promise (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) and check the response inside the `PrivateRoute`: `this.isLoggedin().then((response) => { // return <RouteComponent ... /> or <Redirect ... /> }`

Answer (score 1):

You can create react component that contains login logic. This component wraps all of the routes that require authenticated users. Check this [article](https://medium.com/the-many/adding-login-and-authentication-sections-to-your-react-or-react-native-app-7767fd251bd1) for solution.